# not getting a page reload when submitting a form on a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

When showing a project, the user can add a decision via a form_for and its partial. Is there some way of avoiding reloading the page and just creating the record silently? In the controller method (adddecision) I have:

```
respond_to do |format|
      if @decision.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@project) }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "show" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => decision.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
```

I've tried redirect_to(:back) etc - still getting a page reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `remote_form_for` to submit the form in the background via Ajax.

```
- remote_form_for :decision, :url => adddecisions_path(:format => 'xml') do
  = submit_tag
```

You can handle the error case (and the success case, if you like) in JavaScript. See the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html).

Comment: Jonathan - doesn't remote_form_for rely on Prototype? I'm trying to go all jQuery. Using two jQuery plugins: form and validate did the trick.

Comment: You got it - `form_for` and `jquery.form` is what you need.